# $state.go() undefined is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im trying to redirect to another page with parameters on my app when a HTTP request is complete:

```
 app.controller("startSess", function($scope, $http, $window, $state){
            var self = this;

            $scope.startNewSession = function(){
                    self.newSessionData = {"nick": thisScope.nick, "password": thisScope.password}; //The password is not sensitive information

                    $http({
                            method: "POST",
                            url: "api/newsession.php",
                            data: $.param({"data": self.newSessionData}),
                            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
                    }).success(function(reply){
                            if(reply.status == "complete"){
                                    $state.go('home'); //This is where the error occurs. 
                            }
                    });
            };
    });
```

Upon executing this code, I get:

```
> Object {} app.js:37 TypeError: undefined is not a function
>     at http://site.co.uk/angular/oneword/scripts/app.js:56:11
>     at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js:72:199
>     at L (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js:100:187)
>     at L (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js:100:187)
>     at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js:101:350
>     at k.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js:112:68)
>     at k.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js:109:147)
>     at k.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js:112:398)
>     at h (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js:72:454)
>     at v (http://ajax

.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js:77:463) an
```

Comment: so what's in $state? please post the relevant code

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateproviderstatestatename-stateconfig Is about the best docu I can find for it. Its already in Angular.

Comment: How are you including ui-router? Please post that code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0UXcQJ22 Thats the rest of my app. I have it all imported properly. I should probably note that Im using DotJem UI Routing

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the fact that Im trying to do it inside the `$http` request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in dotjem routing its: `$state.goto('home', {/* OPTIONAL: Params here */});` and ***not***: `$state.go('blah', {/* OPTIONAL: Params here */})`

Comment: it's just called dotjem routing or dotjem angular routing btw ;)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Jens! :D